# Router blocks traffic because no D flag

Tags: router, traffic, blocking

I have a following issue

On my desktop computer I can't access internet. Precisely, i can't ping router. However I can ping other machines on local network and i'm getting IP from DHCP located on the same router.

In router log messages I found "Saturday November 21, 2009 14:10:07 Block MY_MAC-AB-A3-5E because no D flag"

I failed to find anything interesting in google.

Any ideas? (How make desktop add D flag to packets or stop router blocking traffic)

Desktop is running on Windows XP arp -a says that machine doesn't now MAC of router, however setting it to be static doesn't help either. Router is D-Link DI-524 I used to have internet on that machine, it stooped working recently, however i can't thing of anything that could cause that.

Comment: That is freaky... have you tried contacting D-Link support?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The TCP/IP Protocol Suite by Behrouz A. Forouzan says:

> The D flag indicates that routing information for this destination has been added to the host routing table by a redirection message from ICMP.

[Thanks Google](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=HsCjH_V04tUC&pg=PA154&lpg=PA154&dq=d+flag+tcpip&source=bl&ots=GEr38wT3f_&sig=iL3TXJEttsTRM0jDQBh1tanRQJs&hl=en&ei=B8wXS9DeGM-B4QaewLjeAg&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=4&ved=0CBEQ6AEwAw#v=onepage&q=&f=false) for that...

So if a host learns of a route by receiving an ICMP redirect response it will add a dynamic entry to its routing table...

What does

```
netstat -rn
```

show on your XP machine  please?

Comment: I've added answer with result of netstat -rn

Comment: Ok, so no weird routing set up which is good.

Dos the Dl-524 support MAC filtering?  Could it have just blocked your MAC address for some reason?  I guess you would need another device (wired or wireless) to test this theory though.

Comment: +1 for answering my question :-P

Comment: I found that indeed MAC was blocked. I need to find drivers (as i've uninstalled them :P) to confirm, but i believe it will fix the issue)

Answer (score 0):

What is the D flag? The DF (Don't Fragment Flag).  If that is the case for Windows XP ping just use the -f flag to set that.

Comment: just tried that, doesn't help (ping can't time limit exceeded, router logs blocking message)

Comment: "ping time limit exceeded"

Answer (score 0):

> netstat -rn
>
> ## Tabela tras
>
> Lista interfejsów
>   0x1 ........................... MS TCP Loopback interface
>
> ## 0x2 ...00 18 f3 ab a3 5e ...... NVIDIA nForce Networking Controller
>
> ===========================================================================
>   Aktywne trasy:
>   Miejsce docelowe w sieci      Maska sieci      Brama      Interfejs      Metr
>
> ```
>      0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0      192.168.0.1   192.168.0.136       20
>
>    127.0.0.0        255.0.0.0        127.0.0.1       127.0.0.1       1
>
>  169.254.0.0      255.255.0.0    192.168.0.136   192.168.0.136       30
>
>  192.168.0.0    255.255.255.0    192.168.0.136   192.168.0.136       20
> ```
>
> 192.168.0.136  255.255.255.255        127.0.0.1       127.0.0.1       20
>
> 192.168.0.255  255.255.255.255    192.168.0.136   192.168.0.136       20
>
> ```
>    224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0    192.168.0.136   192.168.0.136       20
> ```
>
> 255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255    192.168.0.136   192.168.0.136       1
>
> ## Domyślna brama:      192.168.0.1.
>
> Trasy trwałe:
>    Brak

Answer (score 0):

Please try to empty your ARP cache by running this in cmd.exe: "arp -d *"